# Using (wrapping in) flexbox, how can all rows have the same number of & dimensions of the first row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Using flexbox, my goal was to have the text 'perfectly' apportioned along the width of the page. By 'perfectly apportioned', I mean:

if there's 3 sections, the centre of the text of each section occurs at fifths of the width of the webpage.

Here is how I achieved this:

```css
footer {
  display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}

footer > * {
  flex-basis: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-right: 50px;
  display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
}

footer > *:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

footer > *:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: green;
}

footer > *:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <section>
    <div>one.</div>
  </section>
    <section>
    <div>two.</div>
  </section>
    <section>
    <div>three.</div>
  </section>
</footer>
```

Great.

Now, my problem is when wrapping occurs, the newly wrapped `section` looks 'off' to me - the text centres to the middle of the page. (This is because the `section`/flex-item's `flex-grow: 1` makes it span the width of the page & it applies `justify-content center`. My current solution?) Implement a media-query, at a guestimated vw, to set the flex-item to use `justify-content: initial`:

```css
footer {
  display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}

footer > * {
  flex-basis: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-right: 50px;
  display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
}

footer > *:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

footer > *:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: green;
}

footer > *:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  footer > * {
    justify-content: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <section>
    <div>one.</div>
  </section>
    <section>
    <div>two.</div>
  </section>
    <section>
    <div>three.</div>
  </section>
</footer>
```

It's...not bad. The problem is we lose the `justify-content: center` property which perfectly proportioned text along the width of the page.

But let's cut to the chase: what I really want is a sort of 'flexible' grid where all rows lower than the 1st row have the same number & dimensions of columns of the first row. This would solve my problem.

What's been people's experiences of trying to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I believe you're looking for is [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). You can specify the structure of a row as in the example below. If I was more clear about the goal you want specifically, I could give a more detailed answer, but assuming all you're asking about is that subsequent rows maintain the same structure as the first, this is the solution.

As someone who was using flexbox exclusively to design webpages no longer than a month ago, I highly recommend a switch to CSS Grid to structure the rows and columns you desire, and using flexbox as a supplement.

Note: The subsequent rows will not have the same background colors as the initial row since your CSS only targets the nth child of the footer.

```css
footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}

footer>* {
  flex-basis: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-right: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

footer>*:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

footer>*:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: green;
}

footer>*:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  footer>* {
    justify-content: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <section>
    <div>one.</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div>two.</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div>three.</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div>one.</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div>two.</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div>three.</div>
  </section>
</footer>
```